# Kendo UI Mobile - Assigning a data's literal value to javascript variable using Kendo's templates

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo's templates and am trying to assign the literal contents of my object's "value" field to a javascript variable. Example of what I'm trying to do is given below:

```
# var a = (#= data.value #) #
```

I keep getting an invalid template error.. is this possible to do with Kendo's templates?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
# var a = data.value #
//and later you will have it available 
#if(a=="foo"){#
//...
#}#
```

You should get the idea.

Comment: that doesn't assign the literal value of data.value to var a. I have html tags in data.value and need to assign the #= data.value # to var a

Comment: What is data.value?  What should 'a' equal if the assignment succeeds?

Comment: Theoretically, if data.value = '<span><h3>Test</h3></span>', then 'var a = Test' would be my desired result, thereby allowing me to use 'var a' as the string 'Test'

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below. You should able to get JavaScript value in Kendo template.

```
#var a = data.value #
```

Do not forget to mark as answer !